# Overriding time from settings page

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

I want to override the time from settings page to app screen. I am attaching 2 pictures one is the app screen where the time need to be override and second one is the settings page[This is the 1st picture i.e; app screen where time need to be override here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQqnf.png). If i want to change to 5:00 pm how can i do it?[This is the second image which is the settings page where when i input time here the time need to change in the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUfzJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I think you are trying to achieve,

1.Have one page in your app (i.e. First image) to show the current time.
2.you want that page to change according to the time set on the phone.

use the following code to get the system time

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
String formattedTime = df.format(c.getTime());
// Now formattedDate have current date/time
TextView.setText(formattedTime); //set it to your time view
```

Using the above code you can have a view set a time to the system time.
PS Make sure you set the time in onResume() method of the activity as well

Comment: It's not working is there any another method or way to do it

Comment: Can you tell me why exactly its not working, what error are you facing

Comment: I had implemented your code what you had given but, while changing the time in settings page and getting back the time is not overriding.

Comment: Make sure you add the same code into onResume method of your activity